# wire function is not executing all time

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to get some apex data when component is loading. For this I have added my logic into two different wire adapter inside the JS. but the 2nd wire function is not getting executed always. if I am clearing the browser cache then its executing fine.
Please let me know what could be the reason.
my js looks like:

```
@wire(checkCap, {cap= : '$cap'})
    checkCapablity({error,data}){
        if(data){
            this.iscap=data;
         }
        if(error){
        }
    }
    @wire(getFeed, {}) // this is not executing always.
    getFeedRecord({error,data}){
        if(data){
           
           }
           
        }
        else if(error){
           
    }
```

in both apex method its cacheable=true

Comment: is one dependant on the other? why do you have an empty object in the prop of the getFeed? what exactly should be the order of execution, if there is one you should prob ably invoke one of them imperatively

Comment: both are independent the blank object is typo mistake

Comment: As wired methods are cached you need to call `refreshApex` when needed fresh data from db or alternatively as suggested by glls, you can call it imperatively.

Comment: Clearing the cache using refreshApex is 99.9% of the time a hack and imperative calls should be used instead.

Comment: It also seems clear that the OP needs to read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) which clearly explains the idea of caching.

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods will work on load, but the first method will always fetch the data when the passed parameter value is changed. As in the 2nd method, you are not passing anything it runs only 1 time.